# NetSuite Saved Search - Highlight Items With Multiple Bins

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I have a Cycle Count saved search (Item, not Transaction) that lists items and the bins that have inventory On Hand. That works fine.

The request is: How do I highlight items that are in multiple bins?

I.e. Item ABC is in bin XYZ-One and XYZ-Two

I'd like to highlight both rows to make the inventory team aware to count it in both bins, or all the bins if more than two.

Hopefully that's enough detail, but I'm more than happy to elaborate if anything is unclear.

Thank you NetSuite gurus. I'm eager for your help :)

Comment: to better understand the search logic, could you export the saved search, 
`you could use this chrome ext. NetSuite: Search Export ` https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp`

Answer (score 1):

In an Item search, you can use the Highlight If (Summary) feature to highlight Items in more than 1 Bin.  In order to use the Highlight Summary feature, your results must also have Summary Types.  So in the results, you'll want to show the # of Bins per Item. To do so for the column that shows Item Name, choose Summary Type = Group.  For the column that shows Bin #/Bin internal id, choose Summary Type = Count.  On the Highlight Summary tab select Condition > Count > filed name of the Bin # > is greater than 1.  Then finish the line settings by selecting a background color to display.